# Opening downloaded file from IE in C#

Tags: c#, .net

We have created an application that registers a custom file extension, and we have client's asking to download it from a web server.  We register the extension on the web server with a MIME type (octet), and it serves it correctly.  IE9 and Chrome both launch the application successfully; IE8 seems to lock the file if the user chooses "Open" from the "Save/Open" dialog.  Is there a way to get IE to release this lock (or whatever)?

Answer (score 1):

Are the downloaded files encrypted (are you using https)?

If so, look at IE8's Internet Options --> Advanced --> Security --> "Do not save encrypted pages to disk". Disable this option.

We've run into this problem while downloading PDF files over a secure connection. IE8 wasn't opening Adobe Reader since the file hasn't been saved on the disk.

Hope this helps.

[]'s